# how do i solve an error caused by flutter phone_state package

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, call

pubspec.yaml file.

`dependencies: flutter: sdk: flutter flutter_phone_state: ^0.5.9 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2`

main.dart file

```
`import 'package:flutter_phone_state/flutter_phone_state.dart';`
```

the error:

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:flutter_phone_state
- package:logging
- package:url_launcher
- package:uuid
- package:url_launcher_platform_interface
- package:crypto
- package:convert
- package:plugin_platform_interface

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: That seems to be a very readable error message. Did you do what it said?

Answer (score 1):

The package you want to import is outdated and won't work with the latest version of Flutter.

The maintainers have not answered any of the questions about bringing it up to the current standard. It seems to be abandoned.

- You can use an outdated version of Flutter yourself (pre 2.12.0) where it would still work.
- Or you could look for an alternative that is still supported.
- Or you could fork it and update it to support [dart-null-safety](/questions/tagged/dart-null-safety) yourself.
- Or you could try one of the existing forks.